# Bound of partials sums $\sum_{k=0}^n f(k)$ for a generic, periodic function

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

There was a [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/382413/37490) recently about if $\left|\sum_{k=0}^n \sin k\right| \leq M$ for some $M$.

I wonder, how far could it be generalized? My idea is:

> Let $f$ be continuous<sup>(*)</sup>, bounded, periodic function with an irrational period $s$ such that $\int_0^s f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x = 0$. Then there is $M$ such that $$\left|\sum_{k=0}^n f(k)\right| \leq M.$$
>
> <sup>(*) Or rather uniformly or absolutely continuous?</sup>

The informal idea is that if the period is irrational, the terms of the sum will be "randomly" placed in the interval and since $f$ is continuous and its integral is 0, they should eventually cancel out, just as if we integrated $f$ using [Monte-Carlo integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_Carlo_Integration).

If it's true, how to prove such a statement? If not, why, and how do we need to strenghten the premisses?

Comment: I found an answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/369816/37490).